# Fetch result from json array column in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 9.5 table(instrument)  having 2 columns instrument_id and user_maps as shown below:

[image]

I want to fetch all instruments based on following conditions:

- Loop through each json object in user_maps
- count the number of json objects having status in Y, N or D
- Count should be more than 2.

Note: user_maps is an array of json object having 2 fields status and userId

Sample user_maps  linked to instrument_id "I01":

```
[
  {
    "status": "Y",
    "userId": "ZU201707120539150007"
  },
  {
    "status": "D",
    "userId": "ZU201707120540510008"
  },
  {
    "status": "I",
    "userId": "ZU201707120542540009"
  },
  {
    "status": "I",
    "userId": "ZU201707011725050001"
  },
  {
    "status": "Y",
    "userId": "ZU201707120552050013"
  }
]
```

Instrument id "I01" should come in final result .

Another, Sample user_maps  linked to instrument_id "I02":

```
[
  {
    "status": "I",
    "userId": "ZU201707120539150007"
  },
  {
    "status": "I",
    "userId": "ZU201707120540510008"
  },
  {
    "status": "I",
    "userId": "ZU201707120542540009"
  },
  {
    "status": "I",
    "userId": "ZU201707011725050001"
  },
  {
    "status": "Y",
    "userId": "ZU201707120552050013"
  }
]
```

Instrument id "I02" should  not come in final result beacuse it has only one json having status in (Y, N,D).

Comment: Can you show the code that you've already written, what went wrong there?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I want to write a postgresql  query

Comment: Json is updated

Comment: @NSDmitry i had reached this far only. But unable to check the count select *,jsonb_array_elements(user_maps) from pp.instrument where user_maps@>'[{"status":"Y"}]' or user_maps@>'[{"status":"N"}]' or user_maps@>'[{"status":"D"}]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your request then this is how you can do it:

```
-- This is just test dataset as you provided
WITH    test( instrument_id, user_maps ) AS (
            VALUES
                (   'I01'::text,
                    $$[
                      { "status": "Y", "userId": "ZU201707120539150007" },
                      { "status": "D", "userId": "ZU201707120540510008" },
                      { "status": "I", "userId": "ZU201707120542540009" },
                      { "status": "I", "userId": "ZU201707011725050001" },
                      { "status": "Y", "userId": "ZU201707120552050013" }
                    ]$$::jsonb ),
                (   'I02'::text,
                    $$[
                      { "status": "I", "userId": "ZU201707120539150007" },
                      { "status": "I", "userId": "ZU201707120540510008" },
                      { "status": "I", "userId": "ZU201707120542540009" },
                      { "status": "I", "userId": "ZU201707011725050001" },
                      { "status": "Y", "userId": "ZU201707120552050013" }
                    ]$$::jsonb )
        )
SELECT  t.instrument_id,
        count( u )
FROM    test t,
        jsonb_array_elements( user_maps ) u     -- does lateral join to get json array elements
WHERE   u -> 'status' ?| ARRAY['Y', 'N', 'D']   -- your search condition
GROUP BY 1
HAVING count( u ) > 2;                          -- the count condition you wanted

 -- This is the result of the query
 instrument_id | count
---------------+-------
 I01           |     3
(1 row)
```

Comment: So, if exists `Y, N and D` you want to count all object elements in that array?

Comment: I edited my answer, will that be correctly meet your expectation now?

Comment: should not include "I"  status . Sorry for the wrong information

Comment: My result should be "I01"  count =3

Comment: Ok, so previous count was correct then counting only `Y, N and D`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149031/discussion-between-kristo-magi-and-javatechy).